# What is the correct way to layer if statements in order to get the desired results

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

[enter image description here]

IMAGE 2 (results)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJYEZ.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6o1c.png)I'm working with data manipulation in **csvs using python + pandas**. 
Example #s

PL       T
0.569999695

0.960002899

1.729999542

1.590000153

1.450000763

1.530002594 
1.530002594

1.770000458

0.890003204

0.490001678

1.11000061

1.340000153

2.390003204 
2.390003204

2.470001221

2.760002136

3.200000763

2.880001068

2.479999542
2.479999542

3.100002289

1.269996643

1.269996643

1.590000153

2.13999939

I have used if statements in the past however this one is very specific and I can't seem to get the syntax working correctly.

If you look at the code I want column '`T`' to be calculated like this
there are a few numbers filled into the row already from previous code and the rest are blank.

The code working will hypothetically run through the rows in column t.

The first rows are mostly blank so it will skip those until it hits a row that has a number in it. `if(df['T'].iat[x-1] != "")`

once it hits the row with a number in it the script will check the logical (if the cell in the row next to it is greater than the cell above it)(if

```
df['PL'].iat[x] > df['PL'].iat[x-1]
```

if that logical is true it will print the cell from next to it over into the column. `df['T'].iat[x] = df['PL'].iat[x]`
and if the logical is false then the cell stays blank

I think the real issue is how it iterates after that step. Right now I think its going back and just checking the last if statement again but I want it to iterate through all of them for each row.

It should read the column above to see if it is blank or filled in and then go through the if statements again only printing a number when all are met.

I have tried multiple arrangements as well as using and/or statements. I just can't seem to get it to print the right results.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df=pd.read_csv(filename)

len1 = len(df)

for x in range(len3): 

       if (df['T'].iat[x-1] != ""):

                if(df['T'].iat[x] == ""):

                    if (df['PL'].iat[x] > df['PL'].iat[x-1]):  

                        df['T'].iat[x] = df['PL'].iat[x]
```

The code displays no error messages however it is not printing the right results. Please let me know if I can explain it any better or if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: What are the results it is printing and what are the results you are expecting. Also if you can post some sample data that will make answering the question easier as well.

Comment: Just added in an image link, thanks for the suggestion. Right now it is just printing the same thing as you see up there with no edits

Comment: Please don't post images but rather type the data into the question or provide code to produce the data into a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

What is df?
if df is a dictionary like object of 2 elements, T and PL, then `len(df)` will return 2.

perhaps you have meant `len(df["T"])` or `len(df["PL"])`?

Comment: df is dataframe with pandas. the length is right because the PL column uses a formula with the same length to get its numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` statement doesn't skip rows until it finds an empty cell - your second `if` statement does that. Your first `if` statement (I think) will cause this to fail when you check the very first row.

Try removing the first `if`. If that doesn't work, try removing the other `if`s too, and see if you are able to set any values at all with `df['T'].iat[x] = df['PL'].iat[x]` - it may be that pandas has a separate method to set values than to get them.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[((df['T'] > df['T'].shift(-1)) & (df['T'] != df['PL'])), 'PL'] = df['T']
```

IIUC, this should do what you want.

EDIT:

```
df.loc[(((df['T'].shift(-1).isnull())&(df['PL'].diff()>0))|(~df['T'].shift().isnull())) , 'T'] = df['PL']
```

This works for me. I don't understand though why in your example why 4.65 and 4.87 are not filled. They fill all the requirements, and are filled in my case.

Comment: where should I enter that?

Comment: this does everything, it replaces all your if statements, I'm slightly confused about exactly what you want, but I think this is what you mean.

Comment: if (df['T'].iat[x+1] == "") and (df['T'].iat[x] != "") and (df['PL'].iat[x+1] > df['PL'].iat[x]):

Comment: I also tried that ^ and then printing the results. I only want it to transfer the number over if all are true. If not it should be left blank. It should wait until there is a number sticking out in the t column. This will trigger to do the next statement and transfer the cell if its greater. Then as it iterates down and prints numbers the first two if statements should continue to loop until the if statement about the number being greater is false. Once that happens it should leave the cells blank until it hits another number sticking out in the T column

Comment: It’s still not very clear what exactly you want. Add another image of the expected output for the image you provided, just manually input the T column values. This will make things very clear.

Comment: Just added an image let me know if I can supply anything else. Thank you

Comment: let me also confirm, are the blank spaces when you read it in to pandas NaN or " "? Also you do not get the correct result when you ran my above code?

Comment: I ran your code and did not get the correct results it just left it blank still. They should be just ""